# Is there a way for Memberships to be non-time dependant? educational course progress type?

Tags: civimember

I am new to CiviCRM, but really impressed so far!  However, am currently building out an educational franchise site that along with time based or session based (the rolling & fixed) memberships they also require a more open-ended and non-time based membership type.
For instance a membership that is active for as long as the student is moving through the educational course, and once they pass the final of that course and advance to the next level (or the next stage: group of course levels) they would then need to renew their membership for that next section of material (renew for the next course or set of courses).  Because the classes are ongoing and students move at their own pace, and also allow open enrollment, this is a critical piece for them.  They also have online courses, which also require membership to access that content.

We are using Drupal, and was planning on using drupal commerce module for these purchases prior to getting into Civi, however, we REALLY like the additional features of the Membership components of Civi, and also want to track/manage the users and their memberships through civi.

I have looked around a little, but unable to find reference on this kind of use case.
Any help on or direction would be MUCH APPRECIATED!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason that the following wouldn't suffice:

set them to 'Lifetime' and then have a process eg via Webform_civicrm (or Rules) to close them off and start the new one when they move up a level

Comment: Hmmmm, that sounds like a solution.  Will figure out a rule setup for that to integrate with the exam & level up process, but seems like that would work.  Thanks much!

Comment: Cool. Helps SE if you +1 and/or Accept